# простейшая валидация e-mail без regexp и без использования list

Tags: python

Уважаемые форумчане, добрый вечер! Есть вопрос, понимаю смысл ошибки, но не могу найти правильное решение данной проблемы. Имеется следующая задача: *напишите валидатор для поля email, используя только пройденный материал + инструкцию, находящуюся в этой задаче. Валидатор - это программа, которая проверяет корректность введенных данных. Если введенный адрес электронной почты валиден, то выведите YES, иначе NO*.

**Входные данные**: email - строковое значение

**Выходные данные**: YES - если email валиден, NO - если email не валиден

**Маска для поля email**: ***@***.___ - где ___ может содержать a-z, A-Z, 0-9 и точки. Каждый из блоков, кроме первого (до символа @) должен содержать хотя бы одну букву.

**Пользоваться регулярными выражениями и списками нельзя**, пытаюсь организовать посимвольное рсанение и проверку того, что после @ точка не является следующим символом.

```python
# Простой валидатор почтового адреса (без использования regual expression)
 
# ввод строки пользователем
input_adr = input()
 
# счетчик первого символа (проверяем есть ли в адресе хотя бы один символ)
inint_count = 0
 
# верный адрес почты
correct_adr = 'alpaRist11@code.com'
 
# поиск символов '.', '@' во входой строке
for i in input_adr:
    at = '@'
    dot = '.'
    
# проверяем наличие первого символа в строке, которую ввел пользователь
# до символа @, первый блок
for inint_count in input_adr:
    if((ord(input_adr[inint_count])>= 48 and ord(input_adr[inint_count])<= 57) or 
       (ord(input_adr[inint_count])>=64 and ord(input_adr[inint_count])<=90) 
       or (ord(input_adr[inint_count])>= 97 and ord(input_adr[inint_count])<= 122)):
        inint_count += 1
# проверяем условия, что после символа @ идет хотя бы один символ,
# что символы @ и . не идут вместе
if(inint_count > 0 and at > 0  and (dot-at) > 0 and (dot+1) < len(input_adr)):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Возникающая ошибка:

```
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
if((ord(input_adr[inint_count]>= 48) and ord(input_adr[inint_count]<= 57)) or
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: А вы не много в скобки ord заключили `ord(input_adr[inint_count]>= 48)`

Comment: я поправил, однако все равно это не решает проблему,  я не могу просто понять как мне правильно организовать проход по циклу, чтобы сравнивать индетичность строк, но при этом и записать условия, о которых говорится в задании

Comment: Вы вот задание привели, а из какой книги оно, чтобы знать что вы изучили там можно было написать?

Comment: это задание на курсах, просто в том и суть, чтобы отработаь то, что именно сейчас проходим, хоть и препод понимает, что регулярные выражения или как раз проверка с помощью встроенных функций существенно упростит задачу...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if((ord(input_adr[inint_count]>= 48) and ord(input_adr[inint_count]<= 57)) or
```

считайте скобки - у вас получается следующее

```
ord(input_adr[inint_count]>= 48)
```

т.е. вы `ord` делаете от булева типа `ord(True)` или `ord(False)`

скорее всего вы имели в виду

```
ord(input_adr[inint_count]) >= 48
```

P.S.

а вообще код по указанным правилам я бы сделал так:

```
address = 'test@A12.ru'

address_parts = address.split('@')

checked = address.count('@') == 1

# проверить наличие точки
checked &= '.' in address_parts[1]

# проверить наличие хотя бы одной буквы
checked &= any(letter.isalpha() for letter in address_parts[1])

# проверить наличие букв, цифр и точки
checked &= all((letter.isalpha() or letter.isdigit() or letter == '.') for letter in address_parts[1])

# ВНИМАНИЕ: в условии не сказано проверять блок до @, так что последнюю проверку можно удалить скорее всего
# проверить наличие букв, цифр и точки
checked &= all((letter.isalpha() or letter.isdigit() or letter == '.') for letter in address_parts[0])

print(checked)
```

P.P.S.

если вообще ничего нельзя использовать, то можно вот такой код:

```
address = 'test@A14.ru'

checked = True

# проверить кол-во символов @
symbols_count = 0

for i in address:
    symbols_count += 1 if i == '@' else 0

checked &= symbols_count == 1

# найти координату '@'
symbol_pos = 0

for pos in range(len(address)):
    if address[pos] == '@':
        symbol_pos = pos + 1
        break

# проверить наличие точки
isDot = False
for pos in range(symbol_pos, len(address)):
    isDot |= address[pos] == '.'

checked &= isDot

# проверить наличие хотя бы одной буквы
isAlpha = False
for pos in range(symbol_pos, len(address)):
    isAlpha |= ord('a') <= ord(address[pos]) <= ord('z') or ord('A') <= ord(address[pos]) <= ord('Z')

checked &= isAlpha

# проверить наличие букв, цифр и точки
isLetters = True
for pos in range(symbol_pos, len(address)):
    isLetters &= ord('a') <= ord(address[pos]) <= ord('z') or ord('A') <= ord(address[pos]) <= ord('Z') or ord('0') <= ord(address[pos]) <= ord('9') or address[pos] == '.'

checked &= isLetters

print(checked)
```

P.P.P.S.

кок который оценивает не только часть после @, но и отдельно блоки между точками в этой части:

```
address = '@a.com'

checked = True

# проверить кол-во символов @
symbols_count = 0

for i in address:
    symbols_count += 1 if i == '@' else 0

checked &= symbols_count == 1

# найти координату '@'
symbol_pos = 0

for pos in range(len(address)):
    if address[pos] == '@':
        symbol_pos = pos + 1
        break

# проверить наличие точки
isDot = False
for pos in range(symbol_pos, len(address)):
    isDot |= address[pos] == '.'

checked &= isDot

# проанализировать блоки (расположенные между точками)
start = symbol_pos
for index in range(symbol_pos, len(address)):
    if address[index] == '.' or index == len(address) - 1:
        finish = index if address[index] == '.' else (index + 1)

        # проверить наличие хотя бы одной буквы
        isAlpha = False
        for pos in range(start, finish):
            isAlpha |= ord('a') <= ord(address[pos]) <= ord('z') or ord('A') <= ord(address[pos]) <= ord('Z')

        checked &= isAlpha

        # проверить наличие букв, цифр и точки
        isLetters = True
        for pos in range(start, finish):
            isLetters &= ord('a') <= ord(address[pos]) <= ord('z') or ord('A') <= ord(address[pos]) <= ord('Z') or ord('0') <= ord(address[pos]) <= ord('9')

        checked &= isLetters

        start = index + 1

print(checked)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131340/discussion-on-answer-by-zhihar---e-mail--regexp---).